# jQuery / Javascript - Create your own ..... feature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, builder

what is the name of a feature (maybe jQuery/js/Ajax) that allows you to build your own item,
here is a sample http://www.bluenile.com/build-your-own-diamond-ring

is there a plugin / library to have that feature ?

thank you in advance

Regards
Yq

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a finished feature that you could plug in and have the same diamond rings constructor at your site.

Comment: @YongkiAgustinus It it is okay, close your question please.